# Can a SearchView have both voiceSearchButton and keyboard's voice input?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, searchview, voice

I'm adding voice search capabilities to my app's search interface. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: initial search interface]

To add voice search, I added a `voiceSearchMode` to my Searchable Configuration, which adds a button in the SearchView to trigger the voice dialog. The interface now looks like this:

[image]

However as you can see on the keyboard's `,` key, the microphone button is now disabled. I can't find any documentation on how to turn it on again, and the only related questions explain how to explicitly disable it.

**Is it possible to have both the system's voice search dialog *and* the keyboard's voice input in a `SearchView`?**

Comment: I think it can be done

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but couldn't find an answer through Google so thought I'd add here what I found. After taking a look at the SearchView's source code I found the following code in `setSearchableInfo` method:

```
if (mVoiceButtonEnabled) {
  // Disable the microphone on the keyboard, as a mic is displayed near the text box
  // TODO: use imeOptions to disable voice input when the new API will be available
  mSearchSrcTextView.setPrivateImeOptions(IME_OPTION_NO_MICROPHONE);
}
```

What I then did was to create a class that extends SearchView, override the setSearchableInfo method and after calling `super.setSearchableInfo` add the following:

```
SearchAutoComplete mSearchSrcTextView = findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
mSearchSrcTextView.setPrivateImeOptions("");
```

Now I have a microphone on the keyboard and one in the SearchView.

Edit: Don't forget to reference your class if you're using it in the menu.

```
app:actionViewClass="your.searchview.class"
```

Comment: Hi @robertapengelly, thanks for your reply! This indeed works, although using undocumented API that might break in future releases (nothing guarantees that `mSearchSrcTextView` will still be there / called this way in next releases). Still, it's the best option so far!